# Does this sound natural?

Tags: word-usage, sentence

Does this sound natural?

> ウェイターはあなたが何かを誂える時を待ちます。
> The waiter is waiting for you ordering something

Answer (score 2):

No. 誂える is more like "have something tailor-made". Like a patron having an artist make a unique piece.
When you use 誂える

- you are getting someone to make something specifically for you, not choosing from the menu
- the item is usually artistic in some sense, and not mass produced
- more crucially, when 誂える is done, the artist completes the work and the patron has it (so if the waiter is still getting the order, the timing is off)

Answer (score 0):

the most common word for order(an item) is the verb 注文する・ちゅうもん する・

Your sentence should be something like **ウェイターはあなたが何かを注文するのを待っています。**

I don't really know the verb 誂える and do not seem to be very common, not sure about it but in case of doubt, use anything else haha.

Comment: The bold sentence would mean the waiter has ordered something.